# Pipeline to manipulate identifiers during contact list import in List Manager

Tags: list-manager

In Sitecore 9.x the contact identifiers are case sensitive and users are uploading contact lists with emails that are not cased correctly. Before I start digging through the pipelines, anyone know off the top of their head the pipeline where the contact import data is being processed. So I can add a pipeline that will case them properly.

There is the pipeline `listManagement.importMediaContacts` and that leads to `Sitecore.ListManagement.Services.Pipelines.ImportMediaContacts.GetContactsFromStream`

That leads to

```
<streamContactImporter type="Sitecore.ListManagement.Import.StreamContactImporter, Sitecore.ListManagement">
   <param ref="/sitecore/import/contactSource"/>
   <param ref="/sitecore/import/contactImporter"/>
   <param type="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseLog, Sitecore.Kernel" resolve="true"/>
</streamContactImporter>
```

The source is this. I think maybe I can override in here.

```
<contactSource type="Sitecore.ListManagement.Import.ValidIdentifierSourceFilter, Sitecore.ListManagement">
    <param type="Sitecore.ListManagement.Import.UniqueIdentifierFilter, Sitecore.ListManagement">
        <param type="Sitecore.ListManagement.Import.RequiredFieldsFilter, Sitecore.ListManagement">
            <param type="Sitecore.ListManagement.Import.IdentifierIndexRangeFilter, Sitecore.ListManagement">
                <param type="Sitecore.ListManagement.Import.CsvContactSource, Sitecore.ListManagement">
                    <param type="Sitecore.ListManagement.Import.CsvReader, Sitecore.ListManagement" resolve="true"/>
                </param>
            </param>
        </param>
    </param>
    <param type="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseLog, Sitecore.Kernel" resolve="true"/>
</contactSource>
```

Or I can write my own xConnect importer

```
<contactImporter type="Sitecore.ListManagement.Import.RequiredMappingFieldRangeValidator, Sitecore.ListManagement">
    <param type="Sitecore.ListManagement.Import.ObservableContactImporter, Sitecore.ListManagement">
        <param type="Sitecore.ListManagement.Import.BatchContactImporter, Sitecore.ListManagement">
            <param type="Sitecore.ListManagement.XConnect.Web.Import.XConnectContactImporter, Sitecore.ListManagement.XConnect.Web">
                <param type="Sitecore.ListManagement.XConnect.Web.XdbClientFactory, Sitecore.ListManagement.XConnect.Web"/>
                    <param ref="/sitecore/import/facetMapper"/>
                        <param type="Sitecore.ListManagement.Configuration.ListManagementSettings, Sitecore.ListManagement" resolve="true"/>
                        <param type="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseLog, Sitecore.Kernel" resolve="true"/>
                    </param>
                <param type="Sitecore.ListManagement.Configuration.ListManagementSettings, Sitecore.ListManagement" resolve="true"/>
            </param>
        <param type="Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.IListOperationRepository, Sitecore.ListManagement" resolve="true"/>
    </param>
</contactImporter>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if I override the import task `Sitecore.ListManagement.XConnect.Web.Import.XConnectContactImporter` I had access to the `IdentifiedContactReference` and could control the case of the identifiers.

#### The code

```
namespace Sitecore.Foundation.Links.Import
{
    using Sitecore.Abstractions;
    using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
    using Sitecore.ListManagement.Configuration;
    using Sitecore.ListManagement.Import;
    using Sitecore.XConnect;
    using Sitecore.XConnect.Client;
    using Sitecore.XConnect.Operations;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Sitecore.ListManagement.XConnect.Web;
    using Sitecore.ListManagement.XConnect.Web.Import;

    public class XConnectContactImporter : IContactImporter
    {
        private readonly IFacetMapper _facetMapper;
        private readonly XdbRequestPerformer _xdbRequestPerformer;

        public XConnectContactImporter(
          IXdbClientFactory xdbClientFactory,
          IFacetMapper facetMapper,
          ListManagementSettings settings,
          BaseLog log)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(xdbClientFactory, nameof(xdbClientFactory));
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(facetMapper, nameof(facetMapper));
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(settings, nameof(settings));
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(log, nameof(log));
            this._facetMapper = facetMapper;
            this._xdbRequestPerformer = new XdbRequestPerformer(xdbClientFactory, settings, log);
        }

        public async Task Import(
          IEnumerable<string[]> contacts,
          ImportOptions options,
          ImportSummary summary)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(contacts, nameof(contacts));
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(options, nameof(options));
            var mappings = options.Mappings;
            var identifierIndex = mappings.IdentifierIndex;
            var facetKeys = mappings.Facets.ToArray();
            await Task.Run(() => this._xdbRequestPerformer.RequestWithRetry(client =>
            {
                var dictionary = new Dictionary<IdentifiedContactReference, string[]>();
                foreach (var contact in contacts)
                {
                    if (mappings.GetIdentifierSourceValue(contact) == Sitecore.Foundation.XdbModels.Identifiers.EmailAddress)
                    {
                        dictionary.Add(new IdentifiedContactReference(Sitecore.Foundation.XdbModels.Identifiers.EmailAddress, contact[identifierIndex].ToLower()), contact);
                    }
                    else if (mappings.GetIdentifierSourceValue(contact) == Sitecore.Foundation.XdbModels.Identifiers.SwimmerIdLoginIdentifier)
                    {
                        dictionary.Add(new IdentifiedContactReference(Sitecore.Foundation.XdbModels.Identifiers.IdLoginIdentifier, contact[identifierIndex].ToUpper()), contact);
                    }
                    else
                        dictionary.Add(new IdentifiedContactReference(mappings.GetIdentifierSourceValue(contact), contact[identifierIndex]), contact);
                }

                foreach (var entityLookupResult in client.Get(dictionary.Keys, new ContactExpandOptions(facetKeys)) 
                                                   ?? (IReadOnlyCollection<IEntityLookupResult<Contact>>)new ReadOnlyCollection<IEntityLookupResult<Contact>>(new List<IEntityLookupResult<Contact>>()))
                {
                    var reference = (IdentifiedContactReference)entityLookupResult.Reference;
                    Contact contact;
                    if (entityLookupResult.Exists)
                        contact = entityLookupResult.Entity;
                    else
                        contact = new Contact(new ContactIdentifier(reference.Source, reference.Identifier, ContactIdentifierType.Known));
                    var compositeMappingResult = new CompositeMappingResult(entityLookupResult.Exists);
                    foreach (var str in facetKeys)
                        compositeMappingResult.Add(this._facetMapper.Map(str, contact.GetFacet<Facet>(str), mappings, dictionary[reference]));
                    compositeMappingResult.Accept(client, contact, summary);
                }
                client.Submit();
                if (client.SyncToken == null)
                    return;
                summary.SyncToken = client.SyncToken;
            }, "importing"));
        }
    }
}
```

#### The patch

Here is the config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
    <sitecore>
        <import>
            <contactImporter type="Sitecore.ListManagement.Import.RequiredMappingFieldRangeValidator, Sitecore.ListManagement">
                <param type="Sitecore.ListManagement.Import.ObservableContactImporter, Sitecore.ListManagement">
                    <param type="Sitecore.ListManagement.Import.BatchContactImporter, Sitecore.ListManagement">

                        <param type="Sitecore.ListManagement.XConnect.Web.Import.XConnectContactImporter, Sitecore.ListManagement.XConnect.Web" >
                            <patch:attribute name="type">Sitecore.Foundation.Lists.Import.XConnectContactImporter, Sitecore.Foundation.Lists</patch:attribute>
                        </param>

                    </param>
                    <param type="Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.IListOperationRepository, Sitecore.ListManagement" resolve ="true"/>
                </param>
            </contactImporter>
        </import>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```